# What does it mean "Rebuilding" in a feature? Can it be resolved?

Tags: 7, features

I did some changes in my local environment, then I updated the 'feature'.

When I try to deploy the change to another environment, but before I can start the 'revert' operation, some parts of the feature are marked as 'Rebuilding'.

The feature components are:
- Field bases
- Field instances
- Strongarm

Additional details

- I cannot use drush in the deployment environment.
- This happened once in the past and it resolved itself after clearing the caches.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal's "Features" reflect a status of:

- rebuild when rebuilding database for latest code for unoverriden features
- revert when rebuilding database for latest code for any state features

Rebuilding updates features that are not deliberately overridden for latest code changes. It works during cache clear but can be slow if there are several features enabled on the site, and if there is a lot to clear in Drupal's caches.

If the server/cache clear and rebuild process are interrupted and freeze up, you may need to reset the lock on the feature state.  See https://www.drupal.org/node/928730

If you find this happens frequently, try increasing the mysql timeout and php memory limits.

You may also want to refer to this troubleshooting post about "overridden" features:  https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/features/troubleshooting-reasons-features-may-be-stuck-as-overridden